# Keycloak/Wildfly How to configure all console logs to JSON format

Tags: json, logging, jboss, wildfly, keycloak

I am using the official Keycloak image and trying to set up JSON format for console logs like this

startup.cli

```
embed-server --server-config=standalone-ha.xml --std-out=echo

/subsystem=logging/json-formatter=JSON:add(exception-output-type=formatted)
/subsystem=logging/console-handler=CONSOLE:write-attribute(name=named-formatter,value=JSON)

stop-embedded-server
```

dockerfile

```
FROM jboss/keycloak:12.0.1
COPY $GIT_KEYCLOAK_HOME/CI/startup.cli /opt/jboss/startup-scripts/startup.cli
```

It kind of works. However, not all logs are in JSON format. there is a big chunk at the start (I believe these are some of the parent JBoss bootstrap logs) still in regular format. And it seems that there are no handlers in standalone.xml (at least I haven't found them)

My question is how to change or possibly disable those logs that are not in JSON format.

LOGS output:

```
-b 0.0.0.0

=========================================================================

Using Embedded H2 database

=========================================================================

Executing cli script: /opt/jboss/startup-scripts/startup.cli

11:12:05,763 INFO [org.jboss.modules] (CLI command executor) JBoss Modules version 1.10.2.Final

11:12:05,903 INFO [org.jboss.msc] (CLI command executor) JBoss MSC version 1.4.12.Final

11:12:05,914 INFO [org.jboss.threads] (CLI command executor) JBoss Threads version 2.4.0.Final

11:12:06,096 INFO [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0049: Keycloak 12.0.1 (WildFly Core 13.0.3.Final) starting

11:12:06,243 INFO [org.jboss.vfs] (MSC service thread 1-3) VFS000002: Failed to clean existing content for temp file provider of type temp. Enable DEBUG level log to find what caused this

11:12:07,154 INFO [org.wildfly.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 20) ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.13.1.Final

11:12:08,345 INFO [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/core-service=management/management-interface=http-interface' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.

11:12:08,464 INFO [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.

11:12:08,675 INFO [org.jboss.as.patching] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYPAT0050: Keycloak cumulative patch ID is: base, one-off patches include: none

11:12:08,692 WARN [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYDM0111: Keystore /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost

11:12:08,836 INFO [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server

11:12:08,840 INFO [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: Keycloak 12.0.1 (WildFly Core 13.0.3.Final) started in 3063ms - Started 56 of 86 services (39 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)

{"outcome" => "success"}

{"outcome" => "success"}

11:12:09,126 INFO [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0050: Keycloak 12.0.1 (WildFly Core 13.0.3.Final) stopped in 25ms

=========================================================================

JBoss Bootstrap Environment

JBOSS_HOME: /opt/jboss/keycloak

JAVA: java

JAVA_OPTS: -server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED

=========================================================================

11:12:09,983 INFO [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.10.2.Final

11:12:10,610 INFO [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.4.12.Final

11:12:10,624 INFO [org.jboss.threads] (main) JBoss Threads version 2.4.0.Final

11:12:10,773 INFO [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0049: Keycloak 12.0.1 (WildFly Core 13.0.3.Final) starting

11:12:10,920 INFO [org.jboss.vfs] (MSC service thread 1-6) VFS000002: Failed to clean existing content for temp file provider of type temp. Enable DEBUG level log to find what caused this

11:12:11,679 INFO [org.wildfly.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 20) ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.13.1.Final

11:12:12,729 INFO [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/core-service=management/management-interface=http-interface' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.

11:12:12,773 INFO [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 10) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.

11:12:13,039 INFO [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)

11:12:13,073 INFO [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-5) XNIO version 3.8.2.Final

11:12:13,083 INFO [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-5) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.8.2.Final

11:12:13,156 INFO [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.

11:12:13,170 INFO [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBoss Remoting version 5.0.19.Final

11:12:13,203 INFO [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.config.smallrye._private] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) WFLYCONF0001: Activating WildFly MicroProfile Config Subsystem

11:12:13,234 INFO [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem

11:12:13,238 INFO [org.jboss.as.clustering.jgroups] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 43) WFLYCLJG0001: Activating JGroups subsystem. JGroups version 4.2.5

11:12:13,193 INFO [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 1.4.23.Final)

11:12:13,210 INFO [org.jboss.as.jaxrs] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 41) WFLYRS0016: RESTEasy version 3.13.2.Final

11:12:13,257 INFO [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.4)

11:12:13,251 INFO [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 40) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 16 IO threads with 128 max task threads based on your 8 available processors

11:12:13,263 INFO [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2

11:12:13,286 INFO [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem

11:12:13,287 WARN [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 57) WFLYTX0013: The node-identifier attribute on the /subsystem=transactions is set to the default value. This is a danger for environments running multiple servers. Please make sure the attribute value is unique.

11:12:13,316 INFO [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.metrics.smallrye] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) WFLYMETRICS0001: Activating Eclipse MicroProfile Metrics Subsystem

11:12:13,340 INFO [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=5.0.3.Final-redhat-00006

11:12:13,345 INFO [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.health.smallrye] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) WFLYHEALTH0001: Activating Eclipse MicroProfile Health Subsystem

11:12:13,390 INFO [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]

11:12:13,396 INFO [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service

11:12:13,427 INFO [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 2.2.2.Final starting

11:12:13,469 WARN [org.wildfly.clustering.web.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) WFLYCLWEBUT0007: No routing provider found for default-server; using legacy provider based on static configuration

11:12:13,541 INFO [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 32 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.

11:12:13,541 INFO [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 128 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.

11:12:13,596 INFO [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path '/opt/jboss/keycloak/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']

11:12:13,611 INFO [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.

11:12:13,627 INFO [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting

11:12:13,740 INFO [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 0.0.0.0:8080

11:12:13,752 INFO [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0006: Undertow AJP listener ajp listening on 0.0.0.0:8009

11:12:13,772 INFO [org.jboss.modcluster] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) MODCLUSTER000001: Initializing mod_cluster version 1.4.1.Final

11:12:13,834 INFO [org.jboss.modcluster] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) MODCLUSTER000032: Listening to proxy advertisements on /224.0.1.105:23364

11:12:14,075 INFO [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYEJB0493: EJB subsystem suspension complete

11:12:14,096 INFO [org.jboss.as.patching] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYPAT0050: Keycloak cumulative patch ID is: base, one-off patches include: none

11:12:14,131 WARN [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYDM0111: Keystore /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost

{"timestamp":"2021-05-28T11:12:14.141Z","sequence":45,"loggerClassName":"org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner.logging.DeploymentScannerLogger_$logger","loggerName":"org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner","level":"INFO","message":"WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/deployments","threadName":"MSC service thread 1-5","threadId":20,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"4fda77e3f17e","processName":"jboss-modules.jar","processId":265}

{"timestamp":"2021-05-28T11:12:14.154Z","sequence":46,"loggerClassName":"org.jboss.as.server.logging.ServerLogger_$logger","loggerName":"org.jboss.as.server.deployment","level":"INFO","message":"WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of \"keycloak-server.war\" (runtime-name: \"keycloak-server.war\")","threadName":"MSC service thread 1-6","threadId":21,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"4fda77e3f17e","processName":"jboss-modules.jar","processId":265}

{"timestamp":"2021-05-28T11:12:14.234Z","sequence":47,"loggerClassName":"org.jboss.as.connector.logging.ConnectorLogger_$logger","loggerName":"org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources","level":"INFO","message":"WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]","threadName":"MSC service thread 1-6","threadId":21,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"4fda77e3f17e","processName":"jboss-modules.jar","processId":265}

{"timestamp":"2021-05-28T11:12:14.246Z","sequence":48,"loggerClassName":"org.jboss.as.connector.logging.ConnectorLogger_$logger","loggerName":"org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources","level":"INFO","message":"WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS]","threadName":"MSC service thread 1-2","threadId":17,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"4fda77e3f17e","processName":"jboss-modules.jar","processId":265}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because during the initial boot a `logging.properties` file is used to configure the log manager until the logging subsystem is activated. There are two options.

1. You copy an already configured `logging.properties` and `standalone-ha.xml` over to your image.
2. In a `RUN` command in your `Dockerfile` configure logging by starting the server, then executing the CLI script.