# kubernetes Keycloak logging in json format

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, logging, keycloak, amazon-eks

I want to reformat the default logging output to json format without code changes

Docker image: jboss/keycloak:16.1.1

The current log structure is the default

```
15:04:16,056 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-5,null) [Context=authenticationSessions] ISPN100002: Starting rebalance with members [], phase READ_OLD_WRITE_ALL, topology id 2
15:04:16,099 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (thread-20,) [Context=offlineClientSessions] ISPN100002: Starting rebalance with members [], phase READ_OLD_WRITE_ALL, topology id 2
```

I tried to use `LOG_CONSOLE_OUTPUT` as described here  https://www.keycloak.org/server/logging but it's not working.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Hey, could you please tell us, what you tried and what you want to achieve ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keycloak/Wildfly How to configure all console logs to JSON format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67738041/keycloak-wildfly-how-to-configure-all-console-logs-to-json-format) you need to use correct doc for your version - that is a reason why provided link doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to use quarkus based Keycloak: Json logging for the quarkus based keycloak is only available since v18, see the [release notes](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/release_notes/index.html#quarkus-distribution) - the guides are at the moment referencing only the latest version.

I heavily recommend to update to this version. Then you could use the log console output variable.

You find the newer container images at [quay](https://quay.io/keycloak/keycloak) instead of dockerhub since v17.

Answer (score 1):

The link you posted is a tutorial for the Quarkus-based distro. However, your docker image is based on Wildfly.

[Here is a Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AnHUqu-Vi_E) which explains how to configure json logging with Wildfly-based distro.